# define android system sleep time interval

Tags: android

I'm writing an app which should shows on the screen if user wasn't interract with phone for some time. (I'm going to write a service which will show an activity after this time)

EDIT: Activity may not be open (that's why I must define non-interaction time in service)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's this awesome method `onUserInteraction()` in the Activity class.
You can store the current time as a long in a variable and display the time difference.

```
onUserInteraction(){
  latestInteractedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

// In some method you want to probably display the time difference
String diff = "Time diff: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - latestInteractedTime);
textView.setText(diff);
```